# Rotated CSS element hidden behind another element

Tags: css, rotation, transform

I'm using 'rotate' to create an advent calendar with opening doors.
The elements form a grid sized using vw and vh.
When I 'open' a door, the stretched perspective of the transformed element is visible above the element, but is hidden underneath elements in the row below (tho' Dev Tools show me the shape is correct).
Can't figure it out - there's a CodePen at https://codepen.io/marklsanders/full/jawqJx/.

Here's some CSS too:

```
figcaption {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility:visible;
    background-color: $color-grey;
    color: $color-white;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: left center;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    width: 100%;

    &:after {
      backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: visible;
      background-color: $color-grey;
      content: "";
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      transform: rotateY(180deg);
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do with z-index property.

First make all z-index property set to 1 of your figure class that is root element of card.

```
figure {
   margin: 0;
   z-index: 1; //z-index property
}
```

Then make opened div z-index property set to 2 to your root element. Like below

```
.card.open {
  z-index: 2; //z-index property added
 }
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/marklsanders/pen/jawqJx

Comment: fab; messed around with z-indexes but obviously not on the right elements. thanks